# Joomla: Include only article title in page

Tags: html, joomla

I would like to only include the title of my article on a specific section of my page.  How can I do so?

It would be great if I could do something like the following:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" attribute="title" />
```

I am using a custom template and would just like to separate the article title from the content.

Comment: This isn't something you would normally do in the template. Instead you would need to create a special component view for com_content that did this. Once you had a view set up, you would link a menu item to this view. What is the page supposed to show? Just one title or many titles?

Comment: @DavidFritsch Each page only needs to show one title and then the content of the article.  Very simple layout.

Comment: That sounds like the core article layout .. how is it different than that?

Comment: @Elin So how do I put the article title at the top of the page, the article content at the bottom of the page, and some other content in between the two?  They need to be separate so I can put the title anywhere I want on the page and the content elsewhere.

Comment: Have you looked at the core layout files? Just move $item->title and $item->text or whatever it is you want to move to where you want it by altering the layouts and putting the change version in your template html folder in the appropriate location.  Also there is an event for displaying outside content after the title and before the  text in the standard layout but you can put that event anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla there no option to show something like,

```
<jdoc:include type="component" attribute="title" />
```

for showing the article title.

You can use Joomla default `com_content` component for this its have all basic layouts available, In additionally you can  [override](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) these layouts to your template folder for making entirely different layouts.

by default Joomla article manager have following layouts.

1) Blog :-
   Showing all article title with its content (the content can be limit with read more option)

2) Category :-
   Show all categories as a link.

3) Single article :-
   Show single article in a page with its title and all

and more.

If you check with menu manager you will get all these options and more with article type.
Just create a menu choose its article type and proper layouts, like blog,single article or category etc.

Hope its make sense..